# Mocking child actor in Akka

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit

I'm trying to write unit tests for my actor and am stuck on basic mocking.
PriceAggregateActor is using akka persistence and I don't want to pass in all the conf for it and would like to mock it completely.

This is the actor that I want to test

```
object CommandPriceActor {
  def apply() = Props(classOf[CommandPriceActor], PriceAggregateActor())
}

class CommandPriceActor(priceAggregateActorProps: Props) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val priceAggregateActor = context.actorOf(priceAggregateActorProps, "priceAggregateActor")
```

So in my tests I'm trying to do something like:

```
class CommandPriceActorTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test-benefits",
  ConfigFactory.parseString("""akka.loggers = ["akka.testkit.TestEventListener"] """))) with FlatSpecLike with Matchers
  with BeforeAndAfterAll with Eventually{

  class MockedChild extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case _ => lala
    }
  }

  val probe = TestProbe()
  val commandPriceActor = TestActorRef(new CommandPriceActor(Props[MockedChild]))
```

I'm always getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class CommandPriceActorTest$MockedChild for arguments []
```

Why is it complaining about mockedChild? It shouldn't take any constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because MockedChild is a child actor of your test. The missing constructor argument is the reference to the test (which is the parent class).

You have three options:

1. Pass the reference to `this` into `Props`
2. Use the named parameter form of `Props`
3. Make MockedChild a top level class (or member of an object)

Option 1

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val mockProps = Props(classOf[MockedChild], this)
val commandPriceActor = TestActorRef(new CommandPriceActor(mockProps))
```

Option 2

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val mockProps = Props(new MockedChild)
val commandPriceActor = TestActorRef(new CommandPriceActor(mockProps))
```

Option 3

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val mockProps = Props(new CommandPriceActorTest.MockedChild)
val commandPriceActor = TestActorRef(new CommandPriceActor(mockProps))

// ....

object CommandPriceActorTest {
  class MockedChild extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case _ => lala
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying but how do I write that in code? :)

Comment: I have added some examples.  The original answer was made in an airport on my phone.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thx Ian :)